# Python equivalent of R's ConnCompLabel

Tags: python, r

I have a code written in `R` and I need to rewrite it in `Python`.
Now I am stuck on `ConnCompLabel` from `SDMTools` `R` package
This is the code I need to rewrite :

```
indice<-function(NDVI,threshold,theo=NULL)
{
  nCell=sum(values(NDVI)>threshold,na.rm=T)
  nPotCell=sum(!is.na(values(NDVI)))
  if(nCell<=1){
    return(1)
  }else{
    require(SDMTools)
    if(is.null(theo)){
      theo=load("DATA/B2-fragTheo.RData")
      theo=get(theo)
    }
    ccl.mat = ConnCompLabel(NDVI>threshold)
    nFrag=max(values(ccl.mat),na.rm=T)
    nFragTheo=(theo$nfragtheo[(theo$ncell)/10000==round(nCell/nPotCell,4)])*nPotCell/10000      
    return(nFrag/nFragTheo)
  }
}
```